# Adding a record to the store in specific place

Tags: extjs

Is there a way to add a record to the store after the specific record not using addSorted?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check `Ext.data.Store.insert(index)` which allows you to insert a record at a specified index. Only thing you need is the index of the record you want to insert it after, thats what you have `Ext.data.Store.find()` for

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.Store

Answer (score 5):

More specific way to add new element(s) in store at first place like...

```
Ext.data.Store.insert(0, [{id: 0, name: '(un-assigned)'}]);
```